# Getting data from user page in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, manifest

I am creating a chrome extension which extracts the inner text of `h2>`  from the page in which the user is browsing. Although I learned about content scripts and have used it but it is not working I don't know where is the problem. If anyone could help me that would be greatly appreciated.

This is the js code:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
var link = document.getElementById('button');
link.addEventListener('click', function() {
 updateresult();
});
});
function updateresult() {
var i;

var x =document.getElementsByTagName("h2");

for(i=0; i< x.length ; i++)
{

    document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = (x[i].innerHTML + "\n");


}}
```

This is the manifest file which I am using:

```
        {
         "manifest_version": 2,

            "name": "Header Extractor",
               "description": "Extension to search header",
               "version": "1.0",

               "browser_action": {
                "default_icon": "icon.png",
                "16": "icon.png",
                  "48": "icon.png",
                  "128": "icon.png",
                 "default_popup":"popup.html",
                  "default_title": "Open And Search headers"
                      },
                       "permissions": [
                           "storage",
                           "activeTab" ,"tabs"
                            ],
                           "content_scripts": [
                    {
                    "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
              "js": [ "popup.js"],
               "run_at": "document_end"
                        }
                            ]
                                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you already created a result `div` to paste your results in?

Also your current function only returns one h2 value. Let's use `concat` to output them all together.

```
function updateresult() {
    var i;
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("h2");
    var string = "";
    for(i=0; i<x.length; i++)
    {
        string.concat(x[i].innerText + "\n");
    }
    document.getElementById("result").innerText = string;
}
```

As a side note, we use `innerText` instead.

Comment: hello there thank you so much for the answer but it is still not working  :(